# Regular Expression Lookbehind Issue

Tags: php, python, regex, lookbehind

I'm trying to write a regular expression to pull blocks of text out of the history files I keep on projects I'm building. At the moment I'm planning on doing this extraction manually in my text editor (either textmate or sublimetext 2), but eventually I'll build this into a scripted process using either python or php (haven't decided yet).

All of the history entries in my history file have the format:

```
YYYY-MM-DD - Chris -- Version: X.X.X
====================================
- Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, vim id libris epicuri
- Et eos veri quodsi appetere, an qui saepe malorum eloquentiam.
...

--
```

Where X is the version number that the work was done under.

I'm trying to pull everything from the version number to the final double dash delimiter which denotes the end of the block of text.

I started by creating the regular expression statement to select the section heading which works:

```
(^[\d]{4}-[\d]{2}-[\d]{2}\s-\s[\w]+\s--\sVersion:\s)[\d\.]+$
```

But when I try to turn the pattern within my parenthesis into the look behind it fails:

```
(?<=^[\d]{4}-[\d]{2}-[\d]{2}\s-\s[\w]+\s--\sVersion:\s)[\d\.]+$
```

I've been looking around and so far it seems like this lookbehind format is correct. I can't seem to figure out what I'm missing. Any ideas?

Comment: Lookbehind's are almost never used like this.

Comment: Gotcha, I guess this is one of those rare cases ;)

Comment: I say almost never because you can simply capture what you want without excluding anything from the match, so your not using it to enforce a condition. You are using it to exclude from a match (group 0) which is not necessary.

Comment: Ah, ok. I didn't realize that's what you meant based on your first comment. I guess I'm still a bit fuzzy on why I wouldn't want to do it the way I outlined. If that statement is what denotes the start of a block of text, I don't want anything but the version number on, and there isn't really a different way of telling where a specific block starts other than that string match, why would I still want to include the string in the look behind?

Comment: Here is an example, no lookbehind: `$string = "2013-11-25 - Chris -- Version: 2.1.7\nwhat-1\n--\n2013-11-25 - Fred -- Version: 2.1.7\nwhat-2";$count = preg_match_all('/^\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}\s-\s(\w+)\s--\sVersion:\s([\d\.]+)(.*?)(?:^--|(?![\S\s]))/sm',$string,$matches);for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++){ print ( "who=" . $matches[1][$i] . "\n" ); print ( "vers=" . $matches[2][$i] . "\n" ); print ( "what=" . $matches[3][$i] . "\n----------\n" );}`

Comment: @sin ah ok. Even after reading through the documentation page I don't think I fully understood that you could access the parts of the regular expression matches like that without seeing an example. Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither PHP nor Python allow arbitrary-length look-behind. So as soon as you have a quantifier like `+` in there it ceases to work.

So your first attempt is the only thing that will work here.

Comment: Awesome! Knowing that I can't do a variable length lookbehind I changed my heading format to `YYYY-MM-DD - Version: X.X.X - Chris` and my statement to `(?<=^[\d]{4}-[\d]{2}-[\d]{2}\s-\sVersion:\s)([\d\.]+\s-\s[\w]+)$`. That way all of my look behind data is fixed width. This actually gives the added benifit of parsing my (or one of the other developers') name out to use it. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

As [Joey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/73070) stated, there is no arbitrary-length lookbehind in php or python. But there is a workaround in PHP ! The `\K` escape sequence.

From the [docs](http://www.pcre.org/pcre.txt) :

> The  escape sequence \K causes any previously matched characters not to
>     be included in the final matched sequence. For example, the pattern:
>
> ```
>    foo\Kbar
> ```
>
> matches "foobar", but reports that it has matched "bar".  This  feature
>     is  similar  to  a lookbehind assertion (described below).  However, in this case, the part of the subject before the real match does not  have to  be of fixed length, as lookbehind assertions do.

After removing some redundant brackets `[]`, your expression would look like

```
(?m)^\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}\s-\s\w+\s--\sVersion:\s\K[\d.]+$
```

[**Online demo**](http://regex101.com/r/lX9sU0)

**Notes:**

- `(?m)` : is an inline [regex modifier](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php)
- You don't need to escape a dot `.` in a character class : `[.]` will match a dot and not any character
- You may add some quantifiers to the white-space characters : `\s*` or `\s+`
- `\w+` will also match underscore `_`, so to exclude it you may use `[^\W_]+`
- Regex *is* **awesome**

Comment: Fantastic! Thanks for adding the notes and the modified statement. I'm still pretty new to regex (I started poking around with it last week) so it's good to see redundancies that can be omitted and tips to note. Also thanks for the link to regex101.com. I didn't know this site existed. This is going to be a HUGE help in the future.

Comment: @ChrisSchmitz Join the [regex chatroom](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25767) for more tips and tricks, you might even discuss your regex issues

Comment: Nice, thanks for another helpful link. I need to spend some time exploring stackoverflow a bit more. I didn't even realize there were chat rooms :P